# how to align two divs having same height?

Tags: html, css

I want to align two `div`s (or something similar) next to each other with same `height`  that help me to achieve this:

[image: SS]

furthermore I'm currently using some HTML code and some css effect for the image:

```css
.hoverAm figure img {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hoverAm figure:hover img {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>AUTUMN OUTFIT</p>
  <p>Some other text</p>
</div>
<div class="hoverAm column" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  <div style="width:100%">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" alt="Charlie Henry Adventure" style="width:100%;height:100%;" />
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with `flexbox`

**Note:** avoid using inline styles.

```css
body,
figure {
  margin: 0
}
.hoverAm {
  display: flex
}
figure,
.text {
  flex: 1;
  background: red
}
.hoverAm figure img {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}
.hoverAm figure:hover img {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverAm column">
  <figure>
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/200x400" alt="Charlie Henry Adventure" />
  </figure>
  <div class="text">
    some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes
    here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some text goes here some
    text goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you @dippas !! just is what I'm looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty easily with the use of `flexbox`. Here's a working simple version:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}

.content {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    background: red;
}
```

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/p4nnyxsw/

**Read more about Flexbox**: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

A tip, next time posting on SO: Post some of the relevant code for your question

Answer (score -1):

As a programmer dealing with CSS always feds me up, so i prefer to use frameworks such as bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/). I don't know the especificatons of your project, but if you are open to suggestions i can make your mind with some lines of code:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
        image 1
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6>
        image 2
      </div>
</div>
```

The number x in col-md-x tells the width of the div, considering that each row should be considered as col-md-12